# Mixing C++ and Objective C

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++

Where can i find a concrete document or a dos and donts documentation on using C++ with Objective-C?

Apple seems to have removed that document from their website and i am all puzzled with collating bits of information from blogs and questions posted here.

Anyone can guide about the  same.

> > When do we use .mm file, while mixing syntax or while using an object in .m file which belongs to a C++ class ?
> >
> > While passing objects between functions belonging to two different language like passing objective-c object to a function in cpp file is it necessary to collect it in void * or can I use (ObjectiveC inteface)*?

Comment: What do you mean by "while using an object in .m file which belongs to a C++ class"?

Comment: @pmjordan: if am doing an composition of C++ object in objective-c interface.

#import "cplusplus.h"
 interface xyz : NSObject {
 {
    Cplusplus * myobj;
 }}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use Objective-C++ whenever you are either `#include`/`#import`ing or directly writing both Objective-C and C++ code in the same file. It's usually obvious with explicit code; the `#include`s are often less so, and you need to take care to avoid "leaking" one of the languages into too much of the other. Your example of `#import`ing a C++ header file is clear-cut: you can only do that with Objective-C++. Note that if your `Cplusplus` was a `struct` type, you could forward-declare it as such instead of `#import`ing a C++ header.

If you do this in a header, it will "poison" the header to only work in that mode. You'll need to actively avoid this, or your whole project will soon end up with only .mm files. [I have documented some techniques in this article](http://philjordan.eu/article/mixing-objective-c-c++-and-objective-c++) and [previously, in this earlier article](http://philjordan.eu/article/strategies-for-using-c++-in-objective-c-projects). For newer versions of Objective-C, you can also add ivars to classes in category extensions. This means you can define C++-typed ivars in your .mm file, *not* the header, which allows .m files to `#import` it.

For your second question (**Please only ask one question at a time**): the `id` type is defined in the `objc.h` header file in terms of C and thus will work in both Objective-C and C++. Likewise, the Objective-C runtime API is exposed in terms of C functions, which will work from C++, too. If you actually want to send messages and access properties on Objective-C objects with the canonical syntax from C++ code, you'll need to switch that file to Objective-C++.

Comment: instead of #import if i do @class (forward declaration) then

Comment: `@class` forward declares an Objective-C class (and is illegal in pure C++). `class` forward declares a C++ class but has no special meaning in Objective-C (you can technically name a variable "class"). In C++, structs and classes are almost exactly the same thing, and structs are inherited from C in Objective-C. So if you define your C++ class as a `struct`, you *can* forward-declare it in an Objective-C header.

Comment: Phil has updated his article since this post; the new one is here: http://philjordan.eu/article/mixing-objective-c-c++-and-objective-c++

Answer (score 3):

Use .mm files when you have a c++ syntax in your code or when including file(s) which contain c++ code.

Mixing C++ with objective-c may be a bit confusing but if you think pointer-wise than it is not a big deal. Treat C++ object instance methods as you would in C++ and the same goes for objective c objects.